# Java: use enums for object initialization

Tags: java, enums

I want to initialize an Object of the class Student. When I create the object I want to use an enum for the datatype "course".
Here my code:

student:

```
private String GivenName;
private String Surname;
private String Module;
private int Matrikelnr;  

public Student(String GivenName, String Surname, Course Module) {
        this.GivenName = GivenName;
        this.Surname = Surname;
        Course this.Module = Module;
        }


        public enum Course {
        AI("Course 1"),
        BWL ("Course 2"),
        VWL("Course 3"),
        MA("Course 4");

        private String name;

        private Course(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }}
```

Im trying to initilize the object student like that

```
Student student = new Student(GivenName, SurName, AI);
```

And  I want that the final Object looks like this:

```
"Max", "Smith", "Course 1"
```

But its not working. Can you guys help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it's not working'?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're after. The object can't "look" like `"Max", "Smith", "Course 1"`. Instead I guess you want some kind of string representation (e.g. JSON) that somehow "looks" like this. Am I right?

Comment: "It's not working" isn't helpful. What isn't? My guess would be this line: `Course this.Module = Module` - the left hand side shouldn't have the type here.

Comment: `Course this.Module = Module;` - that can't work. You're trying to redefine a variable (the name should start with a lowercase character btw) which isn't supported. Try `this.module = module.name` and change the field name to `module`. Also note that `name()` already exists for enums so another field name might be better, e.g. `courseName`.

Comment: A final note: if you're already using enums which are more typesafe than strings. Thus it seems unwise to lose information by storing a string in your student instead of the enum that's already being passed.

Comment: the object cant be initialized. I think the Course Parameter isnt correct and also the constructor ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is you seem to be defining your `enum` in the wrong place but it is not clear because you haven't posted complete code.

Here I have it working. Note that I have *fixed* your naming.

```
class Student {
    private String givenName;
    private String surname;
    private String module;

    public Student(String givenName, String surname, Course module) {
        this.givenName = givenName;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.module = module.name;
    }
}

public enum Course {
    AI("Course 1"),
    BWL("Course 2"),
    VWL("Course 3"),
    MA("Course 4");

    private final String name;

    private Course(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    Student student = new Student("Given name", "surname", AI);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @OldCurmudgeon !! :)

Comment: @JMAD2016 - BTW - I agree with @Thomas's comment that you should really store the `module` as a `Course` rather than a `String` - it's much more flexible that way.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler error/warning messages are helpful to anyone ready to help you.

That said, you must tell java that AI is a member of the Course enum.

Student student = new Student(GivenName, SurName, Course.AI);